# BargainFinderMaxRQ Alternate Days Response No Availability Error

Tags: sabre

I am trying to get results from BargainFinderMaxRQ for Alternate Days, like in plus 3 days or minus 3 days. It always shows `No Availability error` in response. By the way, the simple request works perfectly. Please, can anyone help?

API Request:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        </SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Target="Production" Version="4.2.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="4.2.0">
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="8YXD">
        <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
            <CompanyName Code="TN" />
        </RequestorID>
        </Source>
    </POS>
   <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
        <DepartureDateTime>2018-08-23T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KHI" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
        <DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="2"/>
            <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
        <DepartureDateTime>2018-08-30T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KHI" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
        <DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="2"/>
            <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true" MaxStopsQuantity="0">

        <CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Y" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <TripType Value="Return" />
            <LongConnectTime Min="780" Max="1200" Enable="true"/>
            <ExcludeCallDirectCarriers Enabled="true"/>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </TravelPreferences>
    <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
        </AirTravelerAvail>
        <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="PKR" >
    <TPA_Extensions>
    </TPA_Extensions>
    </PriceRequestInformation>
    </TravelerInfoSummary>

    <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction Debug="0">
            <RequestType Name="ALTDATES"/>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
    </TPA_Extensions>

</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have 3 question to better help you 1)Are you using production or test Environment 2) If on test are you using prod credentials or the one from the dev website? 3) Did you talk to your account manager regarding this - afaik this needs to be activated on the account/TJR side?

Comment: i did try from both environment, but the same result. is this needs to be activated by account manager. because i did everything and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be activated by the account manager as Thomas mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE MAKE THREE CHANGES AND IT WILL WORK PERFECTLY

1) SET ACTION NAME AS  BargainFinderMax_ADRQ

```
<eb:Service eb:type="OTA">BargainFinderMax_ADRQ</eb:Service>
<eb:Action>BargainFinderMax_ADRQ</eb:Action>
```

2) SET NUMBER OF DAYS FOR FLEXIBILITY

```
<DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="1"/> OR
<DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="3"/> OR
<DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="7"/>
```

3) SET REQUEST TYPE NAME

```
<RequestType Name="AD1"/> OR
<RequestType Name="AD3"/> OR
<RequestType Name="AD7"/>
```